# Filter with mongo.db and javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am implementing a search bar, front end works and I also implemented the backend and I m rendering the page but I don't see any results:

Backend code:

```
  var search = req.query.search;
  var query = { deleted: false, active: true };

  if (search) {
    var searchQuery = ".*" + search + ".*";
    _.extend(query, { name: { $regex: searchQuery, $options: 'i' } });
  }

  console.log(query);

  Product.find(query, function(err, products) {
    res.render('discover', {
      title: 'Discover',
      products: products,
      category: category,
      search: search
    });
  });
};
```

This is my route:

```
  app.get('/discover/search', discover.discover);
```

And this is the code for my front end:

```
div.row
  div.col-lg-6
  div.col-lg-6(style='text-align: right;')
    div.col-sm-6
      form(action="/discover/search")
        .input-group
          input.form-control(type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search" value=search)
          span.input-group-btn
            button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit' style='border-right: 0px;') Go!
```

I am doing a console log and this is what I see:

{ deleted: false,
  active: true,
  tags: 'search',
  name: { '$regex': '.*Tom.*', '$options': 'i' } }

I do not get any error message - I just see a blank page when I do the search even though there is a product on my page named Tom.

I can't figure out what I m doing wrong. I thought it might be the regex and I tried changing it but I still see the same problem. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you console log out the search/filtered results? Take the UI out of the equation?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by search/filtered results? I am doing a console.log on the query now (you can see it in the code I copied) and I also included the results I get.

Comment: Well, you're getting the data from somewhere, then filtering using search. Log that to the console and see if at least the filter logic is working properly.

Comment: When I m logging it I don t see anything .. it shows me that "products" is empty. Probably the filter logic is wrong, and not the front end.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `.*` at all with your regex. Only 'Tom' is needed.

Another note: the stars aren't there in your regex which prints: `.Tom.`. Still, the dot character does not match new lines which could be a problem.

Comment: I deleted the ".*" but it still does not work..I get an empty array back when I hit Search